# Inconsistency in append 'rect' with text

Tags: d3.js

Any thoughts on why the text is missing for the first rectangle yet others are all fine?

http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/bhwpu/

```
vis = d3.select("#chart")
         .append('svg')
         .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("fill", "pink")
        .attr('class', 'chart');

vis.append("g") // container element
       .attr("class", "x axis") // so we can style it with CSS
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") // move into position
       .call(xAxis); // add to the visualisation

//add in the y axis
vis.append("g") // container element
    .attr("class", "y axis") // so we can style it with CSS
    .call(yAxis); // add to the visualisation
```

Comment: This is because you're selecting all text elements and there's a text element on the page already. This is matched to the data and doesn't appear in the enter selection. To fix, e.g. assign a distinguishing class -- http://jsfiddle.net/bhwpu/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and great solution.  I fixed in this version http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/Bvaud/  but for some reason the text doesn't exit properly.  Is this a related issue?

Comment: You're setting `style` to "label" instead of `class` (and this won't do anything) -- http://jsfiddle.net/Bvaud/1/

Comment: Thanks again.  I missed that change in your first reply!  d3.js is amazing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bvaud/1/

How do I get label on left + line?   This is what I found:  

orient("right).tickSize(width,0,0)      -label + line
orient("right).tickSize(-width,0,0)     -label no line
orient("left).tickSize(width,0,0)       -no label no line
orient("left).tickSize(-width,0,0)      -line no label

Comment: I don't know where in your 344 lines of code you're making this change. It may be better to post a separate question about this.

Comment: Sorry.   Its line 223.   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yRange).tickSize(6).orient("left").tickSize(width,0,0);

Comment: The labels were getting cut off at the margin of the SVG -- translate the container element. You also set the opacity of the line to 0. http://jsfiddle.net/Bvaud/2/